# Align a CSS element with a set width

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a CSS element which is supposed to be a fixed width of 1000 pixels.  Here's the CSS code I have:

```
#content
{
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    position:absolute;
    top:110px;
    width:1000px;
}
```

Tis sets the width, location, and color perfectly, but it's always aligned to the left.  I want the entire block of text aligned to the center.  I tried using HTML to do it:

```
<div id="content" align="center">
Some test content
</div>
```

however this only alignes the text inside of the element, not the element itself.  Here's what it looks like:

http://gyazo.com/b44a28edfecb9cbfc3a5afe93fa08d8a

Any help aligning it to the center is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should center the `div` with css instead.

Something like this:

```
#content
{
background-color:#DDDDDD;
width:1000px;
margin: 110px auto; /*center the element and set top margin to 110px*/
}

<div id="content">
Some test content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute;` to center it horizontally.

I can't see much of your html structure. If your vertical position is affected by this, then try changing `margin:auto` to:

`margin: 110px auto 0;` or `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: I'm trying to center it horizontally

Comment: @RyanSparks I know, I typed vertically by accident!

Comment: Oh thanks!
I changed it to relative, but it aligns it vertically and horizontally, when i only want it to align horizontally...

Comment: @RyanSparks Then use `margin: 0 auto` instead of `margin:auto`

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't do anything that `margin:auto;` doesn't already do

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` sets top and bottom margin to zero. I can't help much more without seeing more of the html structure and it's css.. What I'd suggest is remove your `position` and `top` rules, then use one of the margin rules given to get your desired layout both horizontally and vertically..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center an element from an absolute position, this one stil should be still in static context.
ex : http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/bNFd5/

```
.absolute {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
.center {
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid;
}
.static {
    padding-top:5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #content{
                background-color:#DDDDDD;
                width:1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
            #wrapper{
            width: 1300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content" align="center">Some test content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```